# How to run AWS Amplify GraphQL API queries on behalf of `owner` authorization in Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Here's the schema:

```
type Notification
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, read, update] }])
  @model {
  content: String!
  id: ID!
}
```

Here's the relevant code in the Lambda function:

```js
const createNotificationRequest = new Request(
  process.env.API_PROJECT_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT,
  {
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: /* GraphQL */ `
                mutation CreateNotification(
                  $input: CreateNotificationInput!
                  $condition: ModelNotificationConditionInput
                ) {
                  createNotification(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
                    content
                    id
                    createdAt
                    updatedAt
                    owner
                  }
                }
              `,
      variables: {
        input: {
          content: "yo",
          owner: `${sub}::${username}`,
        },
      },
    }),
    headers: {
      // Authorization: somethingGoesHere,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    method: "POST",
  }
);
const createNotificationRequestResult = await fetch(
  createNotificationRequest
);
console.log(createNotificationRequestResult);
```

Here's the result:

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://abcdefg.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql',
    status: 401,
    statusText: 'Unauthorized',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

As shown, my Lambda function is not authorized to create Notification objects for the `owner` (note that I have access to the owner's `sub` and `username`).

Is this possible to accomplish in a Lambda function?

I've tried adding IAM permissions to my Lambda function; that seemed to get me no where (unless I'm doing something wrong).

Comment: Are you able to get access to the user's JWT token from a previous query? That's how I'm solving this problem when the user is the one who initiated the request.